# Check if virtualhost is working using terminal

Tags: linux, terminal, apache-http-server

I have set up a LAMP server remotely and have ssh access to it. But I haven't managed to configure HTTP access to the site.

I changed the `www` directory to my home directory and want to know if there is a way that I can check that `apache2` is serving pages from the directory using the terminal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can check this if you have a text based browser installed on your server. Normally you should have at least one of the following installed by default: `w3m`, `links2`, `links`, `lynx`. Just try out one of these commands, followed by the location of the page you want to check, e.g.

```
w3m http://localhost/index.html
```

Answer (score 0):

The first thing you should try is checking whether apache is actually running. Since you have ssh access to the machine, you can do so running the following command:

```
sudo service apache2 status
```

If it is, the simplest way to check if it is serving the required pages would be to use a browser to visit a URL like this:

```
http://your_server_ip
```

If you have configured your `apache2.conf` file correctly, it should show the default page for the website you have in your home folder.